# What words in English sound aggressive to native speakers(not a semantically, but phonetically/ associatively) and why?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, word-usage, pronunciation, psycholinguistics

What words in English sound aggressive to native (not a semantically, but phonetically/ associatively) and why?
it can be not a "bunch of examples" only, but a generalized rule, if you can, it will be better too.

This question not about a meaning of words(and not about any sentences or context), but about separated words or affixes.

---

I suggest and ask to open this question again, because:

1. The question is not "opinion-based", this isn't the case:
2. The mass "subjective" perceptions for linguistics is an objective
   relation as the very aspect of language - languages don't exist
   outside of people and psychology, and never and nowhere has any
   language in this form existed. In this way, any linguistic
   question can be called as "psychological" since all linguistic
   actions occur in the human mentality only.

"Psychology of phonetics" - such an universal thing it just does not exist at all.
But in this forum is tag "psycholinguistics" and a similar questions.

3. And the question definitely has no more to do with neuroscience-psychology than with linguistics - since we are talking about words and affixes, and also only the specifics of the English language. Neurology-psychology as a whole deals with other issues, and although there is an intersection, the question is much more linguistic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129213/discussion-on-question-by--what-words-in-english-sound-aggressive-to-nativ).

Answer (score 0):

You can get fired for using a word that is unrelated to but vaguely reminiscent of the N-word.

Two examples are [*niggardly*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_niggardly) and the Chinese phrase [*nei ge*.](https://www.npr.org/2020/09/16/913693813/professor-is-at-center-of-controversy-over-chinese-word-that-sounded-like-racial) Granted, the last one is not an English word, but it was being used in an English sentence.

Comment: "nei ge" - what is it ? well, interesting, but it's not a very clear. And where does the Chinese have to do with it? We are talking here about massive English reactions ... and so - not about something "indecent" or not in accordance with some official rules, namely, causing the emotion of aggression (of fear mb) ... But this curious.. Please, could you explain more ?

Comment: "nei ge" - well, i understand :> But it's specific rasists/antirasist-company association, i'm interesting in others too... :>

Answer (score 0):

Language isn’t related to emotion in an isolated fashion.

**Any word can sound aggressive.**

Consider the word “Hey”. It can sound friendly, neutral or aggressive etc depending on the tone of voice, history of interaction, presence of a weapon, intensity of eye contact, and so on.

Comments on Stack Exchange show that aggressive intent isn’t even required for some comments to sound aggressive to some people.

You ask about words that "phonetically" sound aggressive or that are "associat[ed]" with aggression, but aggression isn't an inherent property of words - it is a property of perception. The context of a given word (the sentence, phrasing, delivery, etc) and the context of the hearer (scared, calm, annoyed, etc) therefore influence whether the word is perceived as aggressive.

Consider the sentence "I will come for you" as an example:

- in the context of an English lesson where a teacher is explaining the function of verbs and tenses, the sentence is typically not associated with aggression.
- spoken by a loving parent, it can even sound comforting.
- spoken by a gangster who thinks you pushed over his motorcycle, it's definitely aggressive.

Comment: "Language isn’t related to emotion in an isolated fashion." You could try to isolate. 
It's not about semantic or tone of voice, etc, that what did you list - all these non-linguistical factors here are completely extraneous and superfluous.

Comment: @Пилум Apropos to the topic ... that sounds aggressive.

Comment: ...not a semantically, but phonetically/associatively..

Comment: @Пилум You've added an article (or possibly an alpha-privative with an extra space) to "semantically" in both your question and now your comment, so I assume it's intentional and not a typo. It renders your sentence ungrammatical, so you'll need to explain what you meant by "a semantically" as opposed to just "semantically". Regarding phonetics and association, my point stands - context determines the level of aggression any given word conveys - both the context of the word and the context of the hearer/reader. I've edited my answer to explain.

Comment: I mean - the question not about meaning of words, but about sounding of words. 
I'm not interesting here in the "context with machine guns in the hands and with big eyes", and i know all about this without any questions on the linguistic forums :)

Comment: @Пилум If the question isn't about language, it is off-topic for EL&U. It might be more appropriate on [psychology.se].

Comment: this question about the language, it's about phonetically/pronounceable and associative component of language and words(and affexes) of it, etc. And about only English mass reaction like a native speakers. 
This question not about non-linguistic things like "context with"...So so. :> 
Well - the absolute any linguistical question is a psychological question, because the carrier of language is the human, and any human have a psychomentality.
 But all this... All this takes us far from the question.

Comment: Could just answer how you think about yourself or about anybody which you know,  and all without general theorizing about "contexts with guns-gangsters-motorbyke" (excepted if it is your private associations with some words phonetically - and which ?).

Comment: ""I will come for you" - and i don't ask any about any sentences. Only about separated words. :) And, mb, affixes.

Comment: @Пилум I've answered the question as asked, including what I've gleaned from your comments regarding your intent. You want to know whether native speakers consider "clip-clop", "grr" or "grass" etc to sound aggressive, but you don't want to consider the context of either the word or the hearer. My answer is that it doesn't make sense to consider something "aggressive" without considering the inner state of the hearer. Note that Stack Exchange requires answers to be definitive, so that constrains how we answer. I'm sorry you didn't get the answer you were looking for.

Comment: I am suggesting this question again because
1. The question is not "opinion-based", this is not the case:
2. The mass "subjective" perceptions for linguistics is an objective relation as the very aspect of language - languages ​​do not exist outside of people and psychology, and never and nowhere has any language in this form existed.
"Psychology of phonetics" - such a universal thing simply does not exist.

Comment: 3. And the question definitely has no more to do with neuroscience-psychology than with linguistics - since we are talking about words and affixes, and also only the specifics of the English language. Neurology-psychology as a whole deals with other issues, and although there is an intersection, the question is much more linguistic.